# ModuleNotFoundError when importing my own python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, python-module

so the problem is that when I try to import something from the module I created, I run into ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<my_module>'.

My project structure is just like this one:

```
├── first.py
└── some_dir
    ├── second.py
    └── third.py
```

You can replicate the problem with these 3 files:

**third.py**

```
""" This is the third file and we store some variable here
    that will be imported to the second """

a = 69
```

**second.py**

```
"""This is the second file. We import 
    a variable from the third and calculate
    the sum of a and b"""

from third import a
b = 10
sum = a + b
```

**first.py**

```
"""This is the first and final file 
    where everything comes together"""
from some_dir.second import c

print(c)
```

And when I run **first.py** I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/moo/goo/foo/first.py", line 3, in <module>
    from some_dir.second import c
  File "/home/username/moo/goo/foo/first.py", line 5, in <module>
    from third import a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'third'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @matszwecja yes thanks. couldn't find it sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use relative imports:

```
from .third import a

c = a + b
```

change sum to c since that's what you're importing.

Keep in mind that the code above won't work if you execute second.py directly because
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Is it possible to keep it working and allow running `second.py` without hacks like having `if __name__ == "__main__":` and importing in a different way based on it?